# Display JSON data from 2 separate JSON files Discord PY

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have 2 separate JSON files, one stores user id and "cash", the other stores user id and "city". The reason I'm storing in separate JSON files is just in case of error it will only lose partial data.

On my leaderboard, I'm trying to display the cash amount a user has as well as what city they are from. Right now, the code gives me a keyerror:

`File "c:\Users\test\Desktop\testclone\TESTCLONE.py", line 2411, in on_message
    msg += '{0}. <@!{1}> {2} Dollars\n\n'.format(number +1, user, cash[user].get('dollars', 0)) + '\nCity: **{}**'.format(homecity[user].get('city',0))
KeyError: '244410964693221377'`

Also, I've tried displaying only the cities as an embed and I'm sure even if I wasn't getting a keyerror, it's not grabbing the city that correlates with the users with the most cash. Is it possible to do what I want if the JSON file "cash" doesn't store the city also?

```
try:
    with open("homecity.json") as fp:
        homecity = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    homecity = {}

def save_homecity():
    with open("homecity.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(homecity, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_city(user: discord.User, city: str):
    id = user.id
    if id not in homecity:
        homecity[id] = {}
    homecity[id]["city"] = homecity[id].get("city", "") + city
    print("{} is now in {}".format(user.name, homecity[id]["city"]))
    save_homecity()

def get_city(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id    
    if id in homecity:
        return homecity[id].get("city", 0)
    return 0

try:
    with open("cash.json") as fp:
        cash = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    cash = {}

def save_cash():
    with open("cash.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(cash, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_dollars(user: discord.User, dollars: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in cash:
        cash[id] = {}
    cash[id]["dollars"] = cash[id].get("dollars", 0) + dollars
    print("{} now has {} dollars".format(user.name, cash[id]["dollars"]))
    save_cash()

def get_dollars(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in cash:
        return cash[id].get("dollars", 0)
    return 0

        if message.content.startswith('!lb cash'):
                cash_leaderboard = sorted(cash, key=lambda x : cash[x].get('dollars', 0), reverse=True)
                msg = ''
                for number, user in enumerate(cash_leaderboard) and enumerate(city_leaderboard):
                    msg += '{}. <@!{}> {} Dollars | **{}**\n\n'.format(number +1, user, cash[user].get('dollars', 0), homecity[user].get('city',0))
                    if number == 10:
                        break
                    else:
                        number += 1

                    embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="TOP LEADERBOARD\nLeaders:",
                    color=0x24d7cf,
                    description=msg
                )
                    embed.set_author(name="BOT", icon_url="")
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url="")
                    embed.set_footer(text="BOT", icon_url="")

                await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my brain was done frying I realized I knew the answer to my question the entire time. I changed

`msg += '{0}. <@!{1}> {2} Dollars\n\n'\n\n'.format(number +1, user, cash[user].get('dollars', 0)) + '\nCity:, **{}**'.format(homecity[user].get('city',0))`

to

`msg += '{}. <@!{}> {} Dollars | **{}**\n\n'.format(number +1, user, cash[user].get('dollars', 0), homecity[user].get('city',0))`